# Use pickled files stored on S3 in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm currently working on an Amazon Web Services Lambda function, where I need to utilize sklearn files that I've created locally but are now stored in S3. I've been stumped on how to actually do this, I've tried a few different methods from boto3's docs but this results in a timeout error:

```
import boto3
import pickle
s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-west-1")
response = s3.get_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key="bin_files/scaler.pkl")
loaded_file = pickle.load(response["Body"])
```

While doing this on the other hand results in a file not found error:

```
 with open(key, 'wb') as data:
     s3.Bucket(event['bucket']).download_fileobj(key, data)


"errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'bin_files/scaler.pkl'"
```

Does anyone have any thoughts or tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correct code:**

```
 with open('scaler.pkl', 'wb') as data:
     s3.Bucket('bucket').download_fileobj(key, data)
```

If you want to download the s3 file to current directory, then you should just pass the ***Filename*** to the file open() method and ***NOT the entire key***. In your case you are passing `bin_files/scaler.pkl` as the ***Filename***.

In your case, the python code will look for `bin_files` directory in the current working directory(*directory where the boto script is getting executed*) and try to write `scaler.pkl` inside the `bin_files` directory. Since the directory doesn't exist, it throws the `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` error.

If you add a *PATH* to the *Filename*, then you should ensure the entire *PATH* exists with appropriate directory permissions.

Comment: That makes sense thank you, I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'scaler.pkl'` the lambda function I'm using has full permissions. Is there something I should be doing on S3?

Comment: Since you are using lambda you can add `/tmp` to the path. I think then it should have the permission. **code**:  `with open('/tmp/scaler.pkl', 'wb') as data:`

Comment: I made the adjustments you suggested: `with open("/tmp/scaler.pkl", 'wb') as data:
        s3.Bucket("mybucket).download_file("bin_files/scaler.pkl", data)` and now I'm getting `"errorMessage": "Filename must be a string"` not sure how that's happening.

Comment: You are getting that error because you are using the `download_file("bin_files/scaler.pkl", data)` API. It expects the 2nd parameter to be a string. see the [doc link](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file) .Instead use the `download_fileobj("bin_files/scaler.pkl", data)` API.